# KDB "value" scope as local variable

Tags: kdb

Is it possible to pass a string as a command inside a function with the function being able to recognize its local variables?
For example, in the following case `value "a+:1";` is unable to recognize `a` is a local variable inside the function.

```
.th.f:{[a]
   iterations: (1+ til 4);
   while[count (iterations);
      value "a+:1";
      iterations: 1_iterations
   a};

test: .th.f[5];
test //gives 5 instead of 10 ...[1 + 2 + 3 + 4]
```

What I need is `value "a+:1";` being able to know `a` is indeed a local variable inside the function.

I am currently working on a much more complicated problem in which passing string as the q command is the only way to resolve.

Comment: What is the "much more complicated problem"?

Answer (score 1):

Although I find it hard to accept that passing a string like that is the only way to fix this, and I don't recommend the use of this solution......something like this might help you:

```
local_context:([]());
.th.f:{[a;v;f] n:?[local_context;();();`$v];
    it:1+til 4;
    while[count it;n:f n;it:1_it];
    n};

q).th.f[5;"a";{x+1}]
9
q).th.f[10;"a";{x+1}]
14
q).th.f[10;"a";{x+2}]
18
```

Here I've split the `"a+:1"` into the variable `"a"` and the function `{x+1}`. If you insist still that it must be `"a+:1"` then you could find a way to translate `"a+:1"` into the variable `"a"` and the function `{x+1}`.

This approach also expands to other variables:

```
local_context:([]());
.th.f:{[a;b;v;f] n:?[local_context;();();`$v];
    it:1+til 4;
    while[count it;n:f n;it:1_it];
    n};

q).th.f[5;100;"a";{x+1}]
9
q).th.f[5;100;"b";{x+1}]
104
q).th.f[10;100;"a";{x+1}]
14
q).th.f[10;100;"b";{x+2}]
108
```

But there has to be a better way to solve your problem if you take a step back

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your parameter within a string where it is processed as a character, you can build the string using join, and apply string on your parameter. So instead of

```
func:{[a] value "a+1"}
```

You could do,

```
func:{[a] value string[a],"+1"}
```

Comment: "I am currently working on a much more complicated problem in which passing string as the q command is the only way to resolve."

Answer (score 0):

So must you keep the "a+:1" part of the code or was this your solution? 
If it is alterable but must be a string I would go for:

```
f:{[a;strFunc]
    itrs:5;
    while[itrs;
        a:value strFunc,string a;
        itrs-:1];
    a};
f[5;"1+"] /Returns 10
```